# grails: pass data from controller response to modalbox

Tags: grails, modal-dialog

I have a gsp page where the user will enter some information and confirms his choice.
so, i need to control data entered before submitting the process.

I want to display response to user in a modal box that user can change some data and then he confirm.
The response is handled by the controller according to the parameters entered by the user and prepares lists of data to render to view.

how can I display a response that replied from controller in a modal box?

**EDIT**

the first page contains a form that allow user to choose to import file in such period and in such directory and in reponse (second page) the application display a list of files that user choose to import some files and ignore others.

first page : index.gsp

```
    <g:form id="imp" name="imp" action="test_import">
Periode :<g:select from="${allPer}" id="per" name="per" optionKey="id"  value="${per }" /><br>Directory :<g:select from="${alldr}" id="dr" name="dr" optionKey="id"  value="${dr}"  /><g:actionSubmit class="button-submit" value="Import"   /> </g:form>
```

controller :

```
def test_import = {
    def dir = null
    def per = null
    def file_to_import 


    if(params.coo != null && params.dr != null) {
        dir= Directory.get(params.dr)
        per = Period.get(params.per)
        file_to_import = Import_file.withCriteria()
                    {
                        eq('directory',dir)
                        eq('periode', per)
                    }
    }



    [file:file_to_import]
}
```

second page: test_import.gsp

```
<g:form id="imp" name="imp" url="[controller:'Import',action:'import_ok']">   


         <table>         
         <tr><td></td>             
                  <td><strong>Ignore</strong></td>
                  <td ><strong>import</strong></td>
                </tr>

                 <g:findAll in="${file_to_import}" expr="1" >
                  <tr>                      
                  <td>${it.name}</td>
                  <td><g:radio id="group_${it.id}" name="group_${it.id}" value="1" checked="${false}"  /></td>                      <td><g:radio id="group_${it.id}" name="group_${it.id}" value="1" checked="${false}"  /></td>                      
                   </tr>
                 </g:findAll></table> <g:actionSubmit class="button-submit" value="Import" action="import_ok" /></form>
```

I want to display the content of second page in a modal box.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Your first paragraph suggests that you are interested in confirming dynamic data from your html form, but further you ask about displaying a response in modalbox. Could you provide more descriptive example? Maybe some code samples. We would like to help you, but we need to know a little bit more details.

Comment: thanks for your response, in fact, it's like a conversation between the application and the user.

Comment: Could you post any code sample showing us this conversation between layers?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this:

in gsp page, I create 2 javacsript functions, the first call the controller and the second uses the response of the action to handle it in a dialog.

```
<a href="javascript:test_import()" onclick="javascript:test_import()">Import</a>
<g:javascript >
    function test_import(){
        ${remoteFunction(action:'test_file_import', controller:'Import', params: '\'dir=\'+document.getElementById(\'dir\').value ',onSuccess: 'CreateDialog(e)')}  
        }

    function CreateDialog(e){   
          var files = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")") 
          return $("<div class='dialog' title=''><p>" + files[0].name + "</p></div>")
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                height:140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Confirm": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
          }
```

and in my controller,

```
def test_file_import = {
    def file = File.get(params.dir)
    FunctionsService fs = new FunctionsService()
    def files= fs.get_files(file)
    render files as JSON
}
```

**Problem**: the params is not read by controller and the files object can not be cast as JSON response!

Thanks for helping.